# Servos don't move

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, servo

I made simple code for a robotic arm, but the servos don't seem to be reacting at all. I made debug code before all the if statements, and those aren't working. I made sure my wiring was good and it is.

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo release1;
Servo release2;
Servo updown;


int pos = 64;    // variable to store the servo position 
int pos2 = 85;
int val = 0;
int val2 = 0;
int val3 = 0;

void setup() 
{ 
    release1.attach(8);
    release2.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
    updown.attach(10);
    release1.write(pos2);
    release2.write(pos2);
    updown.write(pos);
} 

void loop() 
{ 
    val = digitalRead(4);  
    val2 = digitalRead(5); 
    val3 = digitalRead(6);
    pos++;
    pos2++; 
    if(val = LOW){
        pos = pos + 15;
    }
    if(val2 = LOW)
    {
        pos = pos - 15;
    }
    if(val3 = LOW)
    {
        pos2 = 180;
    }
    if(val3 = HIGH){
        pos2 = 0;
    }
    release1.write(pos2);
    release2.write(pos2);
    updown.write(pos);
}
```

I'm using this code and it still wont work.

```
/* Sweep
 by BARRAGAN <http://barraganstudio.com> 
 This example code is in the public domain.

 modified 8 Nov 2013
 by Scott Fitzgerald
 http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep
*/ 

#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position 

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  for(pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=0; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debug the digitalRead function? Start with just one value and see if the motor moves. Maybe the position variable is changing too fast. Make sure the servo gets to the desired position by giving it some time.

Comment: Look at my edit.

Comment: This is the basic code for servos, it works okay for my Arduino UNO. Have you selected the right arduino before burning the code? Try changing the pin, maybe it is not working properly. It seems a board issue.

Comment: How are your connections to the servo motor? Usually the red is +5V, brown is GND and orange is the signal you connect to the attached pin in the code.

Comment: Did some test, all pins seem to be working fine, and yes the connections are right.

Comment: What is the model of your motor? Are you using enough power supply for it? In some cases just Arduino's 5V output is not enough... You need an external power supply.

Comment: SG90 motor, so im using plenty of voltage for it, it moves when I first plug it in but thats its.

Comment: 5V is enough for it. Have you tried different digital pins to attach in the Servo library? Another way is to check if the signal is correct by testing with logic analyzer.

Comment: I used different pins for it, I never heard of a logic analyzer, what is it and how would I use it for an arduino/servo?

Comment: It is a device where you can plug in digital signals and analyze some behaviors. For example: see periods, frequencies and then debug you application. In this case you could see if the PWM generated to control the servo is based on the correct frequency accepted by the servo. They work using a specific period during "on" time and that could indicate where your problem is located.

Comment: Well I dont have one I used arduino 1,0 and that didn't work either, I will try with another computer later.

Comment: Try another board and update the IDE's version as well.

Comment: Have you tried the servo [without using the Arduino](http://www.homofaciens.com/technics-base-circuits-servos_en_navion.htm) ?

Answer (score 1):

I made debug code before all the if statements, and those aren't working.

```
if(val2 = LOW)
{
  pos = pos - 15;
}
if(val3 = LOW)
{
  pos2 = 180;
}
if(val3 = HIGH){
  pos2 = 0;
}
```

That's because they are coded wrongly. Doing `val2 = LOW` **assigns** LOW to val2 and then tests it (which means it will fail the test). They should read:

```
if(val2 == LOW)
{
  pos = pos - 15;
}
if(val3 == LOW)
{
  pos2 = 180;
}
if(val3 == HIGH){
  pos2 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried uploading on a computer with windows 8 freshed installed and it still wont work, i tried serval differn't servo motors, looks like the arduino it self is broken.